# Como puedo mandarle una autenticacion basica (usuario y contraseña) al Soap Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

Quiero consumir un servicio Soap, pero necesito mandarle una Autenticacion Basica (usuario y contraseña) para poder consumirlo. Queria saber si es posible hacerlo con este Request, que solo me pide un `ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList`, pero tambien necesito mandarle las credenciales que por lo que entendi del codigo solo tiene acceso otra clase llamada `ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListClient`

ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList:

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style")]
[DataContract]
public partial class ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList
{
    [XmlElement(Order = 0)]
    private string customeridField;
    
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    private string pedidoCliField;
    
    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    private string pedidoSapField;
```

Cada Elemento tiene su propio Setter y Getter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el Client (el cual le cambie el nombre a SoapClient para que sea mas entendible)

```
  public partial class SoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ServiceReference1.Z_WS_CUSTOMER_INVOICE_GET_LIST>, ServiceReference1.Z_WS_CUSTOMER_INVOICE_GET_LIST
{
    public SoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SoapAuthenticationHeadear
{
    public SoapAuthenticationHeadear() { }

    public static void Create(string username, string password)
    {
        string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
    }
}
```